# Extract the content of text to be used in a Zapier action

Tags: zapier

Can someone please help with a code that will extract a name from a text. I am trying to create an action in a Zapier that will extract the Firstname and Lastname from a gmail. I've tried to modify the "Simple Email Extraction" example given here https://zapier.com/help/code/#introductory-examples , but need someone to point me in the right direction. The example gmail will look like this:

Navn: **Firstname Lastname**
Adresse: Streetadress
PostNr/Sted: Postalcode City
E-post: emailadress
Mobil: mobilephone

What I need to extract is the content of "**Firstname Lastname**" into an output that can be used in the action.

Comment: Could you use the [Zapier email parser](https://parser.zapier.com/) for this?

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Zapier email parser suggested by Matt solved this problem.